He mentioned he likes swimming when we were having a conversation at the party
Is this grammatically correct? Or should it be:
He mentioned he likED swimming when we were having a conversation at the party
or WHILE we were..

Thanks for your response, that was just a mistake that I forgot the we! Could you please let me know about the grammar otherwise?

He liked swimming [until sth bad happened], but not now. Or he still likes swimming. I don't understand the purpose of the last four words of the question. Are they an attempt to ask another question that assumes we know what you are asking?
